# cmake: how to build opencv in both debug and release mode?

Tags: debugging, opencv, build, cmake, release

I am using Cmake GUI 2.8 to build opencv 2.4.10 on a linux machine. I want to build both Debug and Release versions at the same time so that I will have two libraries /lib/Debug and /lib/Release.

I notice that opencv has parameter `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` but don't know how to enable both types.

How do I configure CMake GUI to do that?

Comment: Is not possible to do them at the same time. You should configure two separate build directories, one for the debug and one for the release builds.

Comment: okie, what a pity. But you answer my question so please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is not possible to do them at the same time. You should configure two separate build directories, one for the debug and one for the release builds.